# getElementById to array to function to switch

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, switch-statement

I'm trying to change my Title and banner BG according to the selected title.

```
function display() {

var gameSelected = ["game_dota2","game_clashroyale","game_csgo","game_fortnite","game_pubg",];
var mmgame = document.getElementById(gameSelected);

  switch (mmgame){
    case "Dota 2":
    var mmgame2 = "Dota 2";
    break;
    case "Clash Royale":
    var mmgame2 = "Clash Royale";
    break;
  }
```

This is the idea how to get what game is selected based on a onclick event.

I'm a beginner and not sure if this is the best way to handle it, if you have any better suggestion please let me know.

Now the next issue would be to figure out what would be the best way to implement that working var to another switch statement that then pushes a new Title and a new BG image to the top of the site using .innerHTML and .src

```
switch (mmgame2){
    case "Dota 2":
      var element = document.getElementById("wht");
      element.innerHTML = mmgame2;
      document.getElementById("whbg").src = dota2_bg;
    break;
    case "Clash Royale":
      var element = document.getElementById("wht");
      element.innerHTML = mmgame2;
      document.getElementById("whbg").src = clashroyale_bg;
    break;
    case "CS:GO":
      var element = document.getElementById("wht");
      element.innerHTML = mmgame2;
      document.getElementById("whbg").src = csgo_bg;
    break;
    case "Fortnite":
      var element = document.getElementById("wht");
      element.innerHTML = mmgame;
      document.getElementById("whbg").src = fornite_bg;
    break;
    case "PUB:G":
      var element = document.getElementById("wht");
      element.innerHTML = mmgame;
      document.getElementById("whbg").src = pubg_bg;
    break;
    default:
      var element = document.getElementById("wht");
      element.innerHTML = "Your Game Is Not Ready Now";
    break;
  }
```

}

Thank you!

Comment: Just a fyi, the correct syntax is `break;`, not `brake;`

Comment: What kind of element are you clicking on?

Comment: When you click on an element, the event listener receives an `Event` object as the argument. You can use `event.target` to get the element that was clicked on, and `event.target.id` to gets its ID. You can then use `switch(event.target.id)` to do different things depending on which one they clicked on.

Comment: `document.getElementById(gameSelected)` makes no sense. The argument has to be a specific ID, not an array of IDs. You could create an array of elements with `allGames = gameSelected.map(id => document.getElementById(id))`

Comment: @Barmar I'm trying to click on a div that contains the following:   <a class="angled-img" onclick="display();">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="assets/images/dota2" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="over-info">
                <div><div>
                        <h4 id="d2">Dota 2</h4>

                    </div></div>
            </div>
        </a>

Comment: @Barmar gonna try your solution right now!

Comment: And how does it determine which game was selected from that?

Comment: You need to change to `onclick="display(event)"`. Or you can use `onclick="display(this)"`, then the target will be the argument to the `display()` function.

Comment: @Barmar is game has a onclick that all links to the function display but also a id to determine the name

Comment: @Barmar when I use event.target I still need to keep the ID flexible as it could change.

Comment: @puddi Good call, maybe the script will be faster without those `brake;`s

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be something like this:

```
var selectedGame = getSelectedGame(); //to be defined

var gamesList = {
    "Dota 2": {
        title: 'Dota 2',
        background: '/path/to/Dota2_bg.png'
    },
    "Clash Royale": {
        title: 'Clash Royale',
        background: '/path/to/ClashRoyale_bg.png'
    },
    // add any more games to here, with any needed attributes
};

var game = gamesList[selectedGame];

element.innerHTML = game.title; //set title to game's title as specified above
document.getElementById("whbg").src = game.background; //set background image
```

This might be a little easier to scale.

Comment: just pushed it and it doesn't seem to work. The points that I've defined as "cs" and "d2" etc. are those the calls for the id in the html code? or how do I make sure that it works based on an event?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by simply creating for each game a .js file.

This will also help to scale it as each game will contain more js code than just the click and change function.

Here is a example of the code for the changes that will be implemented for each game:

```
function display_dota2(){
  var element = document.getElementById("wht");
   element.innerHTML = "Dota 2"; //set title to game's title as specified above
  var dota2_bg = "../src/header_bg/dota2.png";
   document.getElementById("whbg").src = dota2_bg; //set background image
}
```